# How to make background picture transparent in pyqt5?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I need to have a window background image which is transparent. I found many solutions in the internet but none of the made image transparent. One of the solutions:

```
class Ui_DialogWINDOW(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(700,700)
        MainLayout = QGridLayout(Dialog)
        self.formLayout = QFormLayout()
        self.groupBox = QGroupBox("")

        # here I tried to make transparent image background
        oImage = QImage("background.png")
        sImage = oImage.scaled(QSize(700,700))
        palette = QPalette()
        palette.setBrush(QPalette.Window, QBrush(sImage))
        Dialog.setPalette(palette)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set the background directly without any image. Have you tried

```
Dialog.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
```

or

```
Dialog.setStyleSheet("#Dialog {background-color:transparent}")
```